# Linear vs Non-Linear

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am attempting some practice problems and I am not sure how to tell if a differential equation is linear or non linear.

The first problem: $$5\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)+5x^2+3=0$$
This is non Linear. Could someone explain that to me?

The second was $$y^3\left(\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}\right)+3x -\left(\frac{8}{y-1}\right)=0$$
This one is linear. Could someone explain that to me? I thought the $\frac{8}{y-1}$ would make it non-linear.

Answer (score 3):

A linear equation only involves the derivatives of the unknown function, eventually multiplied by continuous functions. In particular, you can't have powers of the function, or of its derivatives (example: the equation $x'(y)^2=x(y)$ is not linear).

Your first example is not linear because you're taking $x$ to the power of two.

In your second example, the function $1/y-1$ is continuous -and so is $y^3$- so your equation is linear.

Comment: Ah I see. So if a differential equation had something like e^2x, would the equation be non linear?

Comment: Assuming $x$ is your unknown function, yes, it'd be non-linear

Comment: ok is a unknown function the independent variable?

Comment: In a differential equation, you have to find a function. That function depends on an independant variable. While the notation you used in your question is valid ($x$ for the unknown funtion, $y$ for the variable) it's not very common, from what I've seen. Usually the funtion is noted $x$ and the variable $t$, or the funtion is noted $y$ and the variable $x$.

Comment: oh ok, so the ode such as x(d^2y/dx^2)+3x-(dy/dx)=e^3x would be non linear?

Comment: No, that ode is linear, you're basically multiplying the derivatives of $y$ by continuous functions. The ode $x(d^2y/dx^2)=e^{3y}$, however, would be non linear.

Comment: ok thank you so much.